# Flutter: Bubbles layout representing data

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, bubble-chart

I am trying to achieve result closely to the image below. It should show bubbles with categories of user spendings. Bubbles should be scaled depending on value and should not overlap each other.

Could somebody help with it, please? I have already tried to use StaggeredGridView and other packages for bubble charts but its unsuccessfully.

[image]

Comment: have you got any results? I have similar problem

Comment: kindly share the flutter package, if you achieve this bubble selection screen @Daniel